# PHP doesn't render properly in Web Browser

Tags: php

Sample PHP code

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat 1-new-line.php 
<?php
echo "Hello
World
Foo Bar!";

$aString = '
First Line
Second Line
Third Line';
echo $aString;
?>

wolf@linux:~$
```

It runs as expected in CLI

```
wolf@linux:~$ php 1-new-line.php 
Hello
World
Foo Bar!
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
wolf@linux:~$
```

But not via browser

[image]

What's wrong in this code? How to render it properly in web browser?

Answer (score 3):

Browsers interpret PHP's output as HTML, and in HTML newlines get replaced by spaces.

If you want to learn how to line-break in a browser, use `<br />` or wrap sentences in `<p>` tags.

You can also tell a browser to treat your output as text, and not HTML. In that case, use the following header (before any output):

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Can you show the right way to use `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`. I've tried it but did not get the output that I wanted.

Comment: The way I wrote it is the way you use it. It must appear before any other output. If that doesn't work, share more information.

Answer (score -1):

You are rendering it in a browser without any HTML formatting. Wrapping it in a `<pre></pre>` tags will preserve its plaintext formatting (newlines and whitespace) when rendered in the browser.

```
<pre>
<?php
echo "Hello
World
Foo Bar!";
</pre>


$aString = '
First Line
Second Line
Third Line';

<pre>
echo $aString;
</pre>
?>
```